# How lexer and parser got implemented?

Tags: typescript, parsing, compilation, lexer

I was discovering how programming languages like TypeScript is implemented so I went to the Github repository.

In the language source `/src/compiler` I found files like **scanner.ts** and **parser.ts** so the code inside these files is TypeScript code.

I cannot understand how the language is implementing itself?
I guess there is some missing pieces I do not know.
Please mention any terminology that might be helpful.

Comment: The first compiler was probably not written in TS. After you have a minimal initial version, you can write the next version of the language in the current stable version

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment. @TitianCernicova-Dragomir

Comment: Look up the term “bootstrapping” and “self-hosted language,” which are the names for the general ideas used here.

Comment: Looks like the oldest available TS source is already written in TS, so unfortunately that history isn't available. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/214df64e287804577afa1fea0184c18c40f7d1ca/src/compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools*, also known as the "dragon book," is an excellent resource for all things parsing and compiler design.